# Using case statement to do binning in sql

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We have a small table in following structure;

```
act_id | ratio
 123   |  0
 234   |  0.001
 235   |  0.05
```

I am trying to use `CASE` statement to add anew column which does bucketing sth like;

```
SELECT act_id,
       ratio,
       CASE WHEN 0 <ratio <= 0.04 THEN '(0,0.04]'
            WHEN ratio > 0.04  THEN ratio END AS new_col
FROM table
```

But it gives the following error; `SQL compilation error: error line 50 at position 56 invalid identifier '"(0,0.04]"'`. The desired output is

```
act_id | ratio | new_col
 123   |  0.   |. 0
 234   |  0.001| (0,0.04]
 235   |  0.05 | 0.05
```

may I know how can we use the CASE statement here to put desired strings in this new_col, using open or closed intervals. Helps appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `case` expression returns a single value.  So you need to return a single type -- strings.  Otherwise, if one branch returns a number and another a string, then the string is converted to a number.  And you get an error:

```
SELECT act_id,
       ratio,
       (CASE WHEN 0 < ratio <= 0.04 THEN '(0,0.04]'
             WHEN ratio > 0.04 THEN ratio::string
        END) AS new_col
FROM table
```

I'm not sure if `0 < ratio <= 0.04` does what you expect.  I would recommend:

```
SELECT act_id,
       ratio,
       (CASE WHEN ratio > 0 and ratio <= 0.04 THEN '(0,0.04]'
             WHEN ratio > 0.04 THEN ratio::string
        END) AS new_col
FROM table
```